# Split grouped data at import

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-excel

I have an excel spreadsheet like the following:
[image: 1]

That results in nine models with that attributes:

- Group
- Column
- Value

I tried to find a solution using Laravel Excel but I'm stuck. The problem is that one row becomes three rows and I don't know how to achive that since I can't overwrite the rows.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Imports;

use App\Models\MyModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\OnEachRow;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Row;

//use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithMapping;

class ForecastImport implements ToModel, OnEachRow
{
    function headingRow(): int { return 2; }

    /**
    * @param array $row
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
    */
    public function model(array $row)
    {
        dd($row);
        return new MyModel([
            'group' => $row[0],
            'column' => $row[1],
            'value' => $row[2]
        ]);
    }

    public function onRow(Row $row)
    {
        $entries = array_map(function($entry) {
            return [
                'group' => $entry[0],
                'column' => $entry[1],
                'value' => $rowentry2]
            ];
        }, array_chunk($row->toArray(), 3));
        /*foreach($entries as $entry) {
            $this->model($entry);
        }*/
        // One row became three
        return $entries;
    }
}
```

Comment: try changing heading row position   public function headingRow(): int
    {
        return 2;
    }

Comment: Yes, that's one more thing, I have to do. I'll add that to my question. But that doesn't answer it.

Comment: Is second row key for row 3 to 5 in database? something like ["group"=>"group_A",'column_1'=>1,'column_2'=>2,'column_3'=>3] for first model and again ["group"=>"group_B",'column_1'=>4,'column_2'=>5,'column_3'=>6] for second model??

Comment: How you are fetching data from models? Can you show data structure that you get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured, it would be the cleanest way if `$rows` would be instance properties that could be modified beforehand so that `onRow()`, `model()` and similar methods would get the real "rows". Other solutions look rather hacky to me since I just need to modify the raw input and would like to continue as usual after that which can't be done with the other solutions. Since `$rows` isn't an instance property, I needed to make several changes:

app/Extends/Maatwebsite/Excel/TransformRows.php

```
namespace App\Extends\Maatwebsite\Excel;

interface TransformRows
{
    public function transformRows(array $rows): array;
}
```

app/Extends/Maatwebsite/Excel/Sheet.php

```
namespace App\Extends\Maatwebsite\Excel;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Sheet as ExcelSheet;

class Sheet extends ExcelSheet
{
    public $test = 'test';
    private array $rows = [];
    /**
     * @param object   $import
     * @param int|null $startRow
     * @param null     $nullValue
     * @param bool     $calculateFormulas
     * @param bool     $formatData
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($import, int $startRow = null, $nullValue = null, $calculateFormulas = false, $formatData = false)
    {
        $rows = parent::toArray($import, $startRow, $nullValue, $calculateFormulas, $formatData);
        if ($import instanceof TransformRows) {
            $rows = $import->transformRows($rows);
        }
        $this->rows = $rows;
        return $rows;
    }
}
```

app/Extends/Maatwebsite/Excel/Reader.php

```
namespace App\Extends\Maatwebsite\Excel;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Reader as BaseReader;
use App\Extends\Maatwebsite\Excel\Sheet;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\SkipsUnknownSheets;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Exceptions\SheetNotFoundException;

class Reader extends BaseReader
{

    /**
     * @param $import
     * @param $sheetImport
     * @param $index
     *
     * @return Sheet|null
     * @throws \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Exception
     * @throws SheetNotFoundException
     */
    protected function getSheet($import, $sheetImport, $index)
    {
        try {
            return Sheet::make($this->spreadsheet, $index);
        } catch (SheetNotFoundException $e) {
            if ($import instanceof SkipsUnknownSheets) {
                $import->onUnknownSheet($index);

                return null;
            }

            if ($sheetImport instanceof SkipsUnknownSheets) {
                $sheetImport->onUnknownSheet($index);

                return null;
            }

            throw $e;
        }
    }
}
```

app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php

```
namespace App\Providers;

use App\Extends\Sheet as ExtendsSheet;
use App\Extends\Maatwebsite\Excel\Reader as ExtendsReader;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Files\Filesystem;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\QueuedWriter;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Sheet;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Writer;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('excel', function ($app) {
            return new Excel(
                $app->make(Writer::class),
                $app->make(QueuedWriter::class),
                $app->make(ExtendsReader::class),
                $app->make(Filesystem::class)
            );
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're on the right track. As mentioned in the related [documentation](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/model.html#handling-persistence-on-your-own), the `OnEachRow` concern supposedly grants you more control over what happens in non-standard-case scenarios, where an entire row isn't necessarily a direct model representation (contrary to the `ToModel` concern). The documentation even advises not to mix both.

In your case, what stops you from populating your models the way you wish? Although I don't quite grasp the three-field structure of your model, I'd suggest you simply go like:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Imports;

use App\Models\MyModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\OnEachRow;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Row;

class ForecastImport implements OnEachRow
{
    function headingRow(): int { return 2; }

    public function onRow(Row $row)
    {
        //splitting the 9-column array into chunks of 3
        $entries = array_map(function($entry) {
            return [
                'group' => $entry[0],
                'column' => $entry[1],
                'value' => $entry[2]
            ];
        }, array_chunk($row->toArray(), 3));

        //populate a model with each chunk
        foreach($entries as $entry) {
            MyModel::create($entry);
        }
    }
}
```

But again, I don't see the correlation with the column and group you're parsing, since you'd be assigning only values. Anyways, you can modify that yourself - the main point being that using `OnEachRow`, you're freer to manage model creation yourself. In this occasion, we're creating 3 model records per row, so I suppose that should suffice. Correct me if I've misunderstood anything. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

If  you have following columns in database table

```
group|column|value
```

then you can

```
<?php

namespace App\Imports;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\OnEachRow;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Imports\HeadingRowFormatter;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Row;

$tempHeading = null;
HeadingRowFormatter::extend('custom', function ($value, $key) use (&$tempHeading) {

    if (!empty($value)) {

        $tempHeading = $value;
    }

    return $key . "-" . $tempHeading;


});

HeadingRowFormatter::default('custom');


class UsersImport implements ToModel, WithHeadingRow, OnEachRow
{
    /**
     * @param array $row
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
     */


    private $firstRow = [];

    public function model(array $row)
    {

        //onrow same logic you can apply here also
        //any one you can use onRow or model

    }

    public function headingRow(): int
    {
        return 1;
    }


    public function onRow(Row $row)
    {

        $rowIndex = $row->getIndex();
        $row = $row->toArray();

        if ($rowIndex == 2) {

            $this->firstRow = $row;

        } else {

            $result = collect($row)->transform(function ($value, $key) {


                $columnName = $this->firstRow[$key];
                $group = explode("-", $key)[1];

                return [
                    'group' => $group,
                    'column' => $columnName,
                    'value' => $value
                ];
            })->values()->toArray();

            echo "<br>****************Start of Row***************<br>";
            dump($result);
            echo "<br>****************End of Row***************<br>";


        }

    }

}
```

so output of `$result` is

[image]

So for each row will get multidimensional array so we can use

```
ModelName::insert($result)
```

or  If you have following columns in database table like below

```
group|column1|column2|column3
```

Then

```
<?php

namespace App\Imports;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\OnEachRow;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Imports\HeadingRowFormatter;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Row;

$tempHeading = null;
HeadingRowFormatter::extend('custom', function ($value, $key) use (&$tempHeading) {

    if (!empty($value)) {

        $tempHeading = $value;
    }

    return $key . "-" . $tempHeading;


});

HeadingRowFormatter::default('custom');


class UsersImport implements ToModel, WithHeadingRow, OnEachRow
{
    /**
     * @param array $row
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
     */


    private $firstRow = [];

    public function model(array $row)
    {

        //onrow same logic you can apply here also
        //any one you can use onRow or model

    }

    public function headingRow(): int
    {
        return 1;
    }


    public function onRow(Row $row)
    {


        $rowIndex = $row->getIndex();
        $row = $row->toArray();

        if ($rowIndex == 2) {

            $this->firstRow = $row;

        } else {
            $rows=[];
             foreach ($row as $key=>$value){
                 $columnName = $this->firstRow[$key];
                 $group = explode("-", $key)[1];
                 $rows[$group]['group']=$group;
                 $rows[$group][$columnName]=$value;
             }
             
            echo "<br>****************Start of Row***************<br>";
            dump(array_values($rows));

            echo "<br>****************End of Row***************<br>";


        }

    }

}
```

Output of `dump(array_values($rows));`

[image]